# What are the sizes used for the different options?

Tags: google-image-search

When searching on Google Images, under "Search Tools" there is a dropdown for "Size".  The options in this list are:

- Large
- Medium
- Icon
- Larger than...
- Exactly...

While the bottom 2 are fairly easy to understand, the other 3 are fairly subjective.  What sizes are included in the "Large" option?  What sizes are considered "Medium"?  How small before an image is considered "Icon"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find the information anywhere, and digging through the JavaScript code didn't help me much either. However, from experimentation it seems:

- **Large**: All really large pictures. Smallest dimension I found is 900 x 900 pixels, but I've seen pictures with width/height of 500 or so pixels (they were balanced, however, with a height/width of 1k+).
- **Medium**: Includes some of the "Icon" images and scarce "Large" images (i.e. 1920 x 1080 px), but generally anything in the range of 300~500 pixels (although very frequently higher).
- **Icon**: Ratio is always 1:1 (width == height). Largest dimension I've seen is 512 x 512 pixels.

I believe it goes by the area of the image, but it's nowhere to be easily found.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not able to see this as an actual answer. It only describes what we already can see on the search. Do you have updated data? Thanks.